# Find the 10 customers who bought the most in the last year?

Tags: sql, sapb1

I would appreciate your help,
This is my query and I don't know what is wrong with it.

i try to get The 10 customers who bought the most in the last year.

Thank you

```
SELECT  TOP 10 
    ORDR.CardCode,
    SUM(QRDR.Quantity) [SUM_Quantities]

FROM ORDR 
    LEFT JOIN
            (
                SELECT
                    ORDR.CardCode [CardCode],
                    RDR1.ItemCode [ItemCode],
                    RDR1.Quantity [Quantity],
                    year(RDR1.DocDate)  [Year_Orders]
                FROM ORDR
                        INNER JOIN RDR1 ON ORDR.DocEntry = RDR1.DocEntry
                WHERE YEAR(RDR1.DocDate) = '2022'
                GROUP BY ORDR.CardCode,RDR1.ItemCode, RDR1.Quantity,RDR1.DocDate 
                ORDER BY Quantity DESC
            ) QRDR ON QRDR.CardCode = ORDR.CardCode
        GROUP BY QRDR.CardCode
        ORDER BY QRDR.Quantity DESC
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Also, what database system is it, Microsoft SQL Server or SAP HANA?

Comment: I don't know if you really need all the extra joins/subquery. But for top 10 you should order by `SUM_Quantities`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `ORDER BY` in subqueries

And your second problem was that you had two times the same table name

so your query should look like

```
SELECT  TOP 10 
    ORDR.CardCode,
    SUM(QRDR2.Quantity) [SUM_Quantities]
FROM ORDR 
    LEFT JOIN
            (
                SELECT
                    ORDR.CardCode [CardCode],
                    RDR1.ItemCode [ItemCode],
                    RDR1.Quantity [Quantity],
                    year(RDR1.DocDate)  [Year_Orders]
                FROM ORDR
                        INNER JOIN RDR1 ON ORDR.DocEntry = RDR1.DocEntry
                WHERE YEAR(RDR1.DocDate) = '2022'
                GROUP BY ORDR.CardCode,RDR1.ItemCode, RDR1.Quantity,RDR1.DocDate 
            ) QRDR2 ON QRDR.CardCode = ORDR2.CardCode
GROUP BY QRDR.CardCode
ORDER BY QRDR2.Quantity DESC
```